# Android layout and namespacing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am bit confused with all the "kind (activity, fragment, view)" of files goes into layout directory. Below code to inflate an expandable list works.

**Activity:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}
```

**activity_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title" />

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
                android:name="com.xx.MyFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**MyFragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, null);
}
```

**fragment_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/my_exp_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, I am inflating activity_test.xml in the main activity, which calls MyFragment and uses fragment_test.xml. If I remove the Linear layout around `ExpandableListView` , it doesn't work. I have seen some codes where fragment only contains view elements. So, what is the rule of thumb, or the concept. When should I use the layout in fragment, when can just use a View element.

One related qn: is it possible to have some kind of namespacing for layout file. It is confusing to have lot of files in layout folder. Is it possible to have sub-directories? (within one orientation/screen configuration)

### EDIT:

To answer Timmmm's questions.
I changed to 
`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);`
didn't really affect the outcome.

The exception is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.xx.MyFragment.onActivityCreated(MyFragment.java:45)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1017)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5011)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I found was, If I don't use the enclosing Linear Layout, it an't find the View.

ExpandableListView eview =(ExpandableListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.my_exp_list);

eview is null, but when I enclose it in LinearLayout, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with any view, and it's hard to know what is wrong without a better error than "it doesn't work". One possibility is the `LayoutParams` are not set, because you should be using this line:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
```

Also maybe it *is* working but you haven't put anything in the list view?

Other notes:

1. You don't need to repeat the `xmlns:`
2. Use `match_parent` instead of `fill_content`. They are the same, but Google changed the name to be clearer.

Regarding the namespaces, I totally agree with you about this. I usually prefix my layouts so they are named like `activity_foo.xml`, `fragment_foo.xml`, `view_bar.xml` and so on. A worse problem is that all view IDs go in the same namespace! It would be nice to be able to do `R.id.activity_foo.ok_button`, because it can get confusing when you type `R.id.` and autocomplete shows every ID from every layout.

There is no way around this other than naming your IDs things like `id="@+id/activity_foo_ok_button"` but I think that is too tedious and verbose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please find the Edit for more details.

Comment: You should probably paste the code for `onActivityCreated()` since that's where the error is.